# What's the best approach to display price ($$$) dynamically from table?

Tags: html, css, laravel

I have a table field that stores the price range. (Out of 5)
I want to display it in this manner.
If the range is 3, then display $$$ and other 2 ($) muted.
What is the best approach or what is this called?
(Check the below image for reference)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of for loop as follows:

```
$range = 3;

for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
    if($i < $range){
        echo "<strong>$</strong>";
    }else{
        echo "<span class='text-muted'>$</span>";
    }
}
```

and you have to add CSS like:

```
.text-muted {
    color: #777;
}
```

### Update

You can also use it as a function:

```
<?php


function displayRangeAsDollar($range){
    
    $boldText = '';
    $mutedText = '';
    
    for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
        if($i < $range){
             $boldText .= '$';
        }else{
            $mutedText .= '$';
        }
    }

return  "<strong>".$boldText."</strong>"."<span class='text-muted'>".$mutedText."</span>";
    
}

echo displayRangeAsDollar(3);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have done it the similar way in my Laravel project.
Do you know any other alternatives or package that does this?
I want to know what is this called

Comment: you could create a function for this, no need to install package for this.

Comment: @Dynamite I have also updated my answer, with this you could reutilize it anywhere.